# Calculate this $4 \times 4$ determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

> Find the value of 
>   $$\begin{vmatrix}
> \cos a & \sin a & \cos a & \sin a \\
> \cos 2a & \sin 2a & 2\cos 2a & 2\sin 2a \\
> \cos 3a & \sin 3a & 3\cos 3a & 3 \sin 3a \\
> \cos 4a & \sin 4a & 4\cos 4a & 4 \sin 4a 
> \end{vmatrix}$$

I tried to add/substract some columns and rows in order to get some $0$-s and maybe get to a $3 \times 3$ determinant, but it didn't work. I also thought about using $\sin 2a, \sin 3a, \sin 4a$ formulas, but it gets too complicated. I think that this isn't so difficult and I don't see something easy.

Comment: try this here http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/rav1.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few column operations you get to
$$-\frac14\begin{vmatrix}
e^{ia}&e^{-ia}&e^{ia}&e^{-ia}\\
e^{2ia}&e^{-2ia}&2e^{2ia}&2e^{-2ia}\\
e^{3ia}&e^{-3ia}&3e^{3ia}&3e^{-3ia}\\
e^{4ia}&e^{-4ia}&4e^{4ia}&4e^{-4ia}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=-\frac14\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&1&1\\
e^{ia}&e^{-ia}&2e^{ia}&2e^{-ia}\\
e^{2ia}&e^{-2ia}&3e^{2ia}&3e^{-2ia}\\
e^{3ia}&e^{-3ia}&4e^{3ia}&4e^{-3ia}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=-\frac14\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
e^{ia}&e^{-ia}&e^{ia}&e^{-ia}\\
e^{2ia}&e^{-2ia}&2e^{2ia}&2e^{-2ia}\\
e^{3ia}&e^{-3ia}&3e^{3ia}&3e^{-3ia}\\
\end{vmatrix}
=-\frac14\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
e^{ia}&e^{-ia}&1&1\\
e^{2ia}&e^{-2ia}&2e^{ia}&2e^{-ia}\\
e^{3ia}&e^{-3ia}&3e^{2ia}&3e^{-2ia}\\
\end{vmatrix}.$$
This last sort of determinant is a variant of the Vandermonde determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1&1&0&0\\
t&u&1&1\\
t^2&u^2&2t&2u\\
t^3&u^3&3t^2&3u^2\\
\end{vmatrix}=-(t-u)^4$$
etc.